# How to force Jaxb to consider Unannotated propeties as Attributes instead of Elements?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Having a Class with lot of properties, by default Jaxb consider Unanotated property as XmlElement,

How to force it to encode all Unanotated properties as XmlAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

With JAXB RI, you could implement a custom annotation reader and configure it with your JAXB RI context:

```
final AnnotationReader<Type, Class, Field, Method> annotationReader = new CustomAnnotationReader();

final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

properties.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, annotationReader);

final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
    "org.jvnet.annox.samples.po",
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
    properties);

final Object myObject = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal( ... );
```

With MOXy you could use XML [bindings](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime003.htm) to configure whatever mappin you want for your properties.

I think a custom annotation reader would be less work.